# Adding a dependencie to a rule without appending the dependency to the total list

Tags: linker, makefile, dependencies

I am developing for an embedded system, which means I have to use a linker script. Which is no big deal. I start off with the following Make rule to link everything together:

```
$(RELEASETARGET) : $(OFILES)
    $(LD) -Tlinker_script.ld --entry ResetISR --gc-sections $(LIBDIR) -o $@ $^ $(LIB)
```

As you can see this line contains an error: linker_script.ld is a dependency of this rule, but it is not mentioned in the dependencies. But if I simply add it to the end of the deps:

```
$(RELEASETARGET) : $(OFILES) linker_script.ld
    $(LD) -Tlinker_script.ld --entry ResetISR --gc-sections $(LIBDIR) -o $@ $^ $(LIB)
```

It also gets added to the list after -o and the program will fail to run on the device.

Neither of these warnings is harmful, but I like to live without them. It is btw not possible to simply remove the -Tlinker_script.ld part and only add the script to the list of dependencies: then the configuration will not be loaded correctly and the program will fail to run on the device.

So, how do I add this dependency without adding it to the list of .o-files?

Comment: Why not just use `$(OFILES)` in place of `$^`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `$(OFILES)`, as @Banthar mentioned.  If you don't want to do that you can use `filter` to return just the object files:

```
$(LD) ... -o $@ $(filter %.o,$^) $(LIB)
```